# regex help in python with alphanumaric

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to filter out inconsistent characters from a string.

Currently I have this..in python

```
name = re.sub('([^a-zA-Z0-9  -\'!$&])',' ', name)
```

But I am trying to include characters such as '()' brackets '/' backslash and forward slash. Somehow it does not work.
Could anyone take a look please..

Comment: If you've found the answer then post it as such and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

A non-regex solution

```
accepted = '''!$*()\/.,>-_=+<:;'"?|'''
allowed = string.digits + string.letters + accepted
filter(allowed.__contains__, name)
```

This will filter the string **name** for non-alphanumeric characters and *negate* to filter the characters listed in **accepted**.

Comment: Very good. I didn't know the ``__contains__`` method. - Your site is also very interesting. I'll read it more thoroughly later. Welcome on SO

Comment: Learning new methods is never a bad thing =). I just updated the url to the blog. Thanks for the interest on it. Let me know what you think after you're done reading.

Answer (score 0):

```
name = re.sub('([^a-zA-Z0-9\[\]\(,\)\+\/ \\-\'!$&])',' ', name)
```